# io operations using lua.vm.js in nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, lua, node-webkit

I am using the npm package [lua.vm.js](https://github.com/kripken/lua.vm.js) to execute some pre-existing lua code in my node webkit based app ([nw](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/)).

The file *newtest.lua* contains:

```
local myFile, err = io.open('/tmp/file.txt')
print(myFile)
print(err)
io.input(myFile)
theContent = io.read('*all')
print(theContent)
```

In my javascript code I am doing:

```
var fs = require('fs');
theFileContent = fs.readFileSync("./newtest.lua", "utf8");
var LuaVM = require('lua.vm.js');
var l = new LuaVM.Lua.State();
l.execute(theFileContent);
```

If I simply execute:

```
lua newtest.lua
```

as expected, I get the content of *'/tmp/file.txt'* printed on the console.

But If I run the same code from the nw-based app, I don't get anything: nothing on the output console and not even the global variable **theContent** set to the right value

**myFile** is **nil** and **err** is **/tmp/file.txt: No such file or directory**

But the file is right there.

I am starting to think that the lua code executed by [lua.vm.js](https://github.com/kripken/lua.vm.js) does not allow io operations. Any idea?

**UPDATE**
I tried to run a simple node app (removing nodewebkit from the picture).
[This is the example.js](http://codebin.org/view/3e7ddfc6) I am running

Comment: A quick look seems to indicate that `lua.vm.js` at least recognizes the io functions. I would assume they are handled correctly but I'm not sure. You are ignoring any errors from `io.open` (the second argument). You also aren't checking for a `nil` return value from the function (which will end up with you calling `io.input(nil)` which will return the current default input file (which you ignore). The call to `io.read` will then possibly block waiting on input alternatively it will return `nil` and then you will call `print(nil)` (which may not do anything). You should add error checking.

Comment: Thanks - I am now checking the error code and I edited the post accordingly

Comment: That file is there *where*? How are you running the javascript code when this is failing to work? What context is it running in?

Comment: the file is in /tmp  I am running from nodewebkit context

Comment: Does node-webkit and/or node.js allow access to/use the system file system? Do you need to tell it to allow that?

Comment: I tried node.js vanilla (no nodewebkit)  see the file linked in the updated. And yes, as far as i know, both node and node-webkit allow access to the file system. I know because i used [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) a lot to read/write file on the file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered over at https://github.com/kripken/lua.vm.js/issues/30 :

lua.vm.js virtualises IO into an in memory virtual file system (using emscripten)
This is because it's primarily targeted at the browser, where real IO doesn't exist.

If you're running in node, you can use the node file functions:

```
local file = js.global:require"fs":open("/tmp/file.txt")
```